# Vba change data pattern from row to list

Tags: vba, excel

How can I change the data format pattern by Macro?
Currently the data is like

```
1. Equation    contents1    contents 2  contents 3
2. ANBCDESF         A            C          E
3. YUIOLUIO         Y            O          I
```

I want to change the data to

```
1. Equation   contents
2. ANBCDESF      A
3. ANBCDESF      C
4. ANBCDESF      E
5. YUIOLUIO      Y
6. YUIOLUIO      O
7. YUIOLUIO      I
```

Comment: Please do not change the question to the point where you are invalidating answers to the original See [Editing question for new answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254521/editing-question-for-new-answer) for a discussion on this subject. In short: if your conditions have changed enough that it invalidates an answer you have previously accepted, leave the current answser accepted and move on to a new question.

Answer (score 1):

here one of the possible variants

```
Sub test()
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim cl As Range, Key As Variant, i&
    i = 1
    For Each cl In Range("B2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        Dic.Add i & ":" & Cells(cl.Row, 1).Value, cl.Value: i = i + 1
    Next cl
    i = 2: [F1] = "Equation": [G1] = "contents"
    For Each Key In Dic
        Cells(i, "F").Value = Split(Key, ":")(1)
        Cells(i, "G").Value = Dic(Key)
        i = i + 1
    Next Key
    Set Dic = Nothing
End Sub
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed the contents a little bit and added a column. How does the code change?

Comment: it depending on range of data, please show sample of the new dataset